# Trying to use google maps, But having an issue

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am working on a Dynamics 365 instance, I am trying to display a google maps that shows the current client and near by clients.

This is the code im using but i am getting an error to start not sure whats going on but if anyone could help it would be awesome.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-26.4420246,133.281323),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('address1_composite').getValue();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(14);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status );
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error it gives me - https://prnt.sc/uh4xzo

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: I havnt really tried to do any thing else but this script, the error is in the screen shot, other then that there is no log that im aware of that it would post to.

Comment: @NicoHaase ^^^^